# How to style ng-repeat elements in Angular 1?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My code is

```
<li ng-repeat="x in stats">
                {{ x.first + '  :  ' + x.second  }}
</li>
```

and javascript code would be

```
$scope.statistics = [{"first" : "Full Name", "second" : "XYZ"},{"first" : "College", "second" : "Amity"}];
```

How can I style x.first and x.second elements particularly? For example how would I style "XYZ" and "Amity" bold?

Comment: `<b>{{x.first}} </b>: {{x.second}} `

Comment: by using elements and not single text nodes....it's not rocket science

Comment: Please use <b></b> tags to make it bold.

Answer (score 0):

Simply wrap it inside an element and apply class on element.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.statistics = [{"first" : "Full Name", "second" : "XYZ"},{"first" : "College", "second" : "Amity"}];
});
```

```css
.bold
{
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <li ng-repeat="x in statistics">
     <span>{{x.first}} :</span>
      <span class="bold">{{x.second}}</span>

</li>

  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just define your css and apply the classes to you elements.

**HTML :**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <li ng-repeat="x in stats">
    <span class="red">{{x.first}} :</span>
    <span class="blue">{{x.second}}</span>
  </li>
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
.red {
  color: red;
}

.blue {
  color: blue;
}
```

**JavaScript (in Controller) :**

```
  $scope.stats = [{
    "first": "Full Name",
    "second": "XYZ"
  }, {
    "first": "College",
    "second": "Amity"
  }];
```

**JSFiddle :**

https://jsfiddle.net/nikdtu/87rgzjmw/